# Why can't my contract be deployed?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to compile and deploy this contract, but it's telling me there's an error in a line. The line is 'contract Atriachw is Standard Token {' 
Please, help me look at it to see what the problem is.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;


/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

contract ERC20Basic {
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) constant returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) constant returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool) {
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of. 
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}


contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;


  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool) {
    var _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

    // Check is not needed because sub(_allowance, _value) will already throw if this condition is not met
    // require (_value <= _allowance);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance.sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool) {

    // To change the approve amount you first have to reduce the addresses`
    // allowance to zero by calling `approve(_spender, 0)` if it is not
    // already 0 to mitigate the race condition described here:
    // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
    require((_value == 0) || (allowed[msg.sender][_spender] == 0));

    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

contract Atriachw is StandardToken {

  string public constant name = "Atriachw";
  string public constant symbol = "AXM";
  uint8 public constant decimals = 18;

  uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 100000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));

  /**
   * @dev Constructor that gives msg.sender all of existing tokens.
   */
  function Atriachw() public {
    totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  }

}

contract Crowdsale {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  // The token being sold
 Atriachw public token;

  // start and end timestamps where investments are allowed (both inclusive)
  uint256 public startTime;
  uint256 public endTime;

  // address where funds are collected
  address public wallet;

  // how many token units a buyer gets per wei
  uint256 public rate;

  // amount of raised money in wei
  uint256 public weiRaised;

  /**
   * event for token purchase logging
   * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens
   * @param beneficiary who got the tokens
   * @param value weis paid for purchase
   * @param amount amount of tokens purchased
   */
  event TokenPurchase(address indexed purchaser, address indexed beneficiary, uint256 value, uint256 amount);


  function Crowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, address _wallet) public {
    require(_startTime >= now);
    require(_endTime >= _startTime);
    require(_rate > 0);
    require(_wallet != address(0));

    token = createTokenContract();
    startTime = _startTime;
    endTime = _endTime;
    rate = _rate;
    wallet = _wallet;
  }

  // creates the token to be sold.
  // override this method to have crowdsale of a specific mintable token.
  function createTokenContract() internal returns (Atriachw) {
    return new Atriachw();
  }


  // fallback function can be used to buy tokens
  function () external payable {
    buyTokens(msg.sender);
  }

  // low level token purchase function
  function buyTokens(address beneficiary) public payable {
    require(beneficiary != address(0));
    require(validPurchase());

    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;

    // calculate token amount to be created
    uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(rate);

    // update state
    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    token.mint(beneficiary, tokens);
    TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);

    forwardFunds();
  }

  // send ether to the fund collection wallet
  // override to create custom fund forwarding mechanisms
  function forwardFunds() internal {
    wallet.transfer(msg.value);
  }

  // @return true if the transaction can buy tokens
  function validPurchase() internal view returns (bool) {
    bool withinPeriod = now >= startTime && now <= endTime;
    bool nonZeroPurchase = msg.value != 0;
    return withinPeriod && nonZeroPurchase;
  }

  // @return true if crowdsale event has ended
  function hasEnded() public view returns (bool) {
    return now > endTime;
  }


}

contract CappedCrowdsale is Crowdsale {
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  uint256 public cap;

  function CappedCrowdsale(uint256 _cap) public {
    require(_cap > 0);
    cap = _cap;
  }

  // overriding Crowdsale#validPurchase to add extra cap logic
  // @return true if investors can buy at the moment
  function validPurchase() internal view returns (bool) {
    bool withinCap = weiRaised.add(msg.value) <= cap;
    return super.validPurchase() && withinCap;
  }

  // overriding Crowdsale#hasEnded to add cap logic
  // @return true if crowdsale event has ended
  function hasEnded() public view returns (bool) {
    bool capReached = weiRaised >= cap;
    return super.hasEnded() || capReached;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi there. The `StandardToken` contract seems to be missing its closing parenthesis/brace. Formatting the code properly - not only in the above question, but during general development - would help avoid simple problems like this. There are probably numerous other similar problems _just because of the formatting_ . Take time to go through things and lay them out properly, with proper indentation (or use a code pretty-fier). It will be time well spent.

Comment: Nice copy and paste from an old version of ERC20 (because of the compiler) without probably understand it by the way. The safemath are not required anymore.